# JS - nice sleep-alike functionality

Tags: javascript, sleep

I have a very CPU-intensive JS function that makes browsers kill it because of long no response. I want to have the function finished, and also i want to be able to use my browser in the meanwhile.

My solution was to implement a sleep-alike functionality in my function after each iteration:

```
<p id="debug"/>
<script>
    function example(i) {
            //do stuff
            if(i < 100) window.setTimeout(function() {example(i+1);}, 100);
    }

    example(0);
</script>
```

The solution works well - but is there is any nicer way to implement this functionality? - without using the unnecessary recursion.

Comment: The `setTimeout` is exactly the function you need. As far as I know, there is no other option.

Comment: There are WebWorkers now, but setTimeout is more compatible, heres a  [Compatibility List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers#Browser_Compatibility)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something called web workers which is similar to Threading. Refer: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: Hm, didn't think about those. Please note that these are a relatively new feature, and [not supported on older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_web_workers#Browser_Compatibility)

Comment: Hmm, its interesting, thank you for sharing the info. I accept this answer even if I cannot use it - my function manipulates the document directly (this manipulation itself is the CPU intense task), to that the web worker does not have access.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sleep = function(period, decision, callback){
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if (decision()) {
            interval = clearInterval(interval);
            callback();
        }
    }, period);
}
```